# Lost link for datasource in projectgroup with same names

Tags: delphi

I have a group of projects in which I have two applications that have similar file names: main form (frmmain) and data module (data).

Delphi very often gets lost and removes the datasourse properties from frmmain because it searches for dataset in the data module from the second project, because it have same name (or at least it seems to me that it is problem).

When this happens and tries to set the property manually, the object inspector shows me the list of datasource from the data module of the second project.

I have this problem with two `projectgroups` - every time I have this same names in main form and `datamodule`.

What can I do with it?

I am using Delphi 10.3.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?  A similar problem which used to occur (mainly pre-D7) was db-aware components losing their connections to datasources in another source module.  It sounds like your prob would be easily avoided by using distinct names.  Another thing which might help is to use the project manager for each project to explicitly add the modules which it actually uses, rather than leave it to the IDE to guess which ones the datasources might be referring to.

Comment: Yes this is a known situation, especially in the modern Delphi where you can open files from different projects at the same time via a project group. There is no solution other than to be sure all the files you might open in 1 project group really have different names! frmServerMain and frmClientMain for example. Another way, is to code the datasource properties into the source code. You know I have done this.

Comment: I was expecting this. I would like to save the links in the code. Only these projects are huge and I can not imagine that ....

I think I have to try to change the name of the data module. It will be a bit of of work, but less so than typing it in the code.

Comment: I've had this problem.. try opening the data module before opening forms that reference it..

Comment: Well, yes, but first of all it will be annoying to remember that. And secondly, I do not always have an influence on it. When I close a project with an open datamodule and form, I do not know in which order the IDE will open them.
It remains to me either to change the name or wait for the fix of it.

Comment: I've had the problem without duplicate unit names.. I'm just asking you to try it so you can rule things out.

Comment: @Insane: *or wait for the fix of it* How would you expect that fix to be made? You've named files the same, thrown them in the same project group, and expect the IDE to be able to figure out which one you really mean to use. The issue will be fixed in the IDE as soon as software is able to read the mind of developers so they can resolve these issues telepathically. In the meantime, it will remain the responsibility of the developer to properly name things to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: And why not? Why IDE can not write the full path to a file in an  project?
When I'm searching for a module, IDE shows which file belongs to which project (even if it is called the same).

Following this path, if I have two forms with the same name in two projects (as in my case), Delphi may have a problem compiling the right form. And it is not.